# Application variable initialised in Controller constructor issue

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc

Using ASP.NET MVC3.

What I'm trying to do is initialize a Controller field/property with an Application state variable.

I.e. in my Application_Start() method I have

```
Application["stats"] = new Stats(); //this is fine
```

Accessing this via a Controller method, e.g.

```
public ActionResult Index()
{
  return View(HttpContext.Application["stats"]); //this is also fine
}
```

works fine too.

```
//blows up with a 'Object reference not set to an object' error.
private Stats stats;
public HomeController()
{
    stats= (Stats)(HttpContext.Application["stats"]);
}
```

Anyone able to explain what I'm failing to understand + how to go about fixing the problem ? If there's a better way, let me know (and just in case you're wondering, I'm not trying to load up application configuration or anything; just to keep live stats on the state of the website)

Thanks in advance

-Marcin

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `HttpContext` is not yet initialize inside a controller constructor and is null.

If you need to access any HttpContext related stuff this could be done at most early inside the [Initialize](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.controller.initialize.aspx) method:

```
public class HomeController: Controller
{
    private Stats stats;

    protected override void Initialize(RequestContext requestContext)
    {
        base.Initialize(requestContext);
        stats = (Stats)(HttpContext.Application["stats"]);
    }
}
```

Comment: Genius ! Thanks heaps for that.

Answer (score 0):

The HttpContext from your question is the property on the controller and as Darin said, that is not yet initialized. You can however use this:

```
private Stats stats;
public HomeController()
{
    stats= (Stats)(System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Application["stats"]);
}
```

Comment: What about unit testing? `HttpContext.Current` kinda kills all hopes :-)

Comment: Absolutely, unit testing will be a "challenge". Your solution is much better than mine. I just wanted to point out that you could get to the HttpContext in the constructor.

Comment: HttpContext.Current is something that you really don't want to use. No matter the circumstances. There are always better ways.

Comment: Thanks for that. Just trying to understand how unit testing would be easier using plain HttpContext rather than System.Web.HttpContext ?  I found http://www.hanselman.com/blog/ASPNETMVCSessionAtMix08TDDAndMvcMockHelpers.aspx which suggests that it's possible to mock it. So would the ability to mock be the only reason ? (Sorry, I've seen a few examples about mocking with Moq but haven't had a serious play with it).